# Boost.Python Makefile to CMakLists.txt

Tags: makefile, cmake, boost-python

I wrote some C++ files to create a shared library, and here is my `Makefile`

```
PYTHON_VERSION = 3.6
PYTHON_HOME_PATH = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
PYTHON_INCLUDE = $(PYTHON_HOME_PATH)/$(PYTHON_VERSION)

BOOST_INC = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib
BOOST_PYTHON_LIB = /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0_1/lib/


TARGET = main
EXTEND_FILE = main_ext

$(TARGET).so:$(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared depend.o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -L$(BOOST_PYTHON_LIB) -lboost_python3 `python3.6m-config --libs --ldflags` -o depend_ext.so
    g++ -shared depend.o $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -L$(BOOST_PYTHON_LIB) -lboost_python3 `python3.6m-config --libs --ldflags` -o $(TARGET).so
    mv $(TARGET).so $(EXTEND_FILE).so

depend.o:depend.cpp
    g++ `python3.6m-config --include` -fPIC -c depend.cpp -O3 -std=c++11

$(TARGET).o:$(TARGET).cpp
    g++ `python3.6m-config --include` -fPIC -c depend.cpp $(TARGET).cpp -O3 -std=c++11

clean:
    rm *.so *.o
```

The `Makefile` can generate the `.so` file. And my `CMakeLists.txt` is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Simulator)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES depend.cpp depend.h main.cpp main.h)
add_executable(Simulator ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARIES /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib)
set(BOOST_PYTHON_LIB /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0_1/lib/)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system date_time python REQUIRED)


message("--> Include dirs of boost: " ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("--> Libs of boost: " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )

find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 REQUIRED)
message("--> Include dirs of Python: " ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
message("--> Libs of Python: " ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} )

include_directories(
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(Simulator
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
        ${BOOST_PYTHON_LIB}
        )
```

But running CMake gives the following errors

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.10.2/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1928 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.67.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_python3
```

I want to build it with Python3 and I have already install boost.python3. How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you invoke `cmake`? Do you provide a `-DBoost_ROOT` option? If so, it seems that `boost-python3` is installed under a different root dir from the rest of Boost (can't check further because I'm not on a mac).

Comment: @compor  I didn't provide the  -DBoost_ROOT

Comment: Is `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include` symlinked under `/usr/local/include`? If so, does the same thing happen with the `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0_1/` subdirs?

Comment: @compor, no `/usr/local/include` includes a dir contains boost-python with other versions.

Comment: @compor Adding `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/` as `-DBoost_ROOT` can generate `Makefile`, but then `make` returns errors.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with that info. You somehow need to install `boost-python3` under the same location where the rest of Boost is located. That's a suspicion, since I cannot reproduce that environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179476/discussion-between-compor-and-goingmyway).

Comment: @compor thank you, I installed `boost-python3` with `brew`.

Comment: @compor, I installed Boost.Python on another server without root permission, the libboost_python  is `libboost_python-py34.so`, I can't make a soft link like `ln -s libboost_python-py34.so libboost_python3.so `. What can I do in the `CMakeLists.txt` file.

Comment: I compiled it too and got `libboost_python35.so.1.68.0`, my options were just `--with-python=python3`. I can't see any support for such suffices by the `FindBoost` module; only for the various version components (major,minor,patch).

Comment: @compor, After contacting the administer of the server, a link has been created and I can `cmake ..` and `make` now. But using above `CMakeLists.txt`, I only got executable file, not the `.so` file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that Homebrew installs `boost_python` under a separate directory (i.e. `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.67.0_1/`) which is different from the rest of the Boost installation (i.e. `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1`).

I'm not on a Mac, thus I'm not exactly certain of the actual directory structure and how much can be done with symlinks (symlinking the Boost Python component directories back into the main Boost installation dir).

So, I built and installed (on Ubuntu Linux) from source the latest Boost version (1.68) using

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/bulk/workbench/boost/install --with-python=python3
```

All components ended up under the `include` and `lib` directories in `/bulk/workbench/boost/install`. Providing that during CMake configuration as in

```
cmake -DBoost_ROOT=/bulk/workbench/boost/install [path-to-my-project-source-dir]
```

and using this in my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
```

it was able to find my `boost_python` module.

Basically, unless you're able to twist the Homebrew installation, it might be more straightforward to build your own Boost.

Comment: I thought Boost.Python was different from Boost. And these days I found Boost.Python is just a subset of Boost. One can install Boost.Python by setting options when installing Boost. However, installation methods and dirs used by Homebrew really made me confused.

Comment: There is no need to add `--with-python=python3` under command `./b2`. Adding it with `./bootstrap.sh`.